# Is this JSON data correct for fexigrid?

Tags: jquery

I'm using json data below for flexigrid, but it doesn't work.

**json.txt**

{'page':1, 'total':1, 'rows':[{'id':1, 'cell':['S1', 'H', 'Jerry']}, {'id':2, 'cell':['S1', 'H', 'Terry']}]}

**javascript:**

```
    $('#idefectreport').flexigrid({
    url: 'json.txt',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    colModel: [
        {display: 'DefectID', name : 'id', width : 40, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
        {display: 'Priority', name : 'priority', width : 180, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
        {display: 'SupportID', name : 'supportid', width : 120, sortable : true, align: 'center'}
    ],
    buttons : [
    {name: 'Add', bclass: 'add'},
    {name: 'Delete', bclass: 'delete'},
    {separator: true}
    ],
    searchitems : [
    {display: 'DefectID', name : 'id'},
    {display: 'Priority', name : 'priority', isdefault: true}
    ],
    height:'auto',
    sortname: "id",
    sortorder: "asc",
    title: 'Defect Report',
    usepager: true,
    useRp: true,
    rp: 10,
    showTableToggleBtn: true
});
```

what's wrong with the code? thanks!

Comment: Just use a html for url. not use any php or asp

Comment: I return xml and everything go right

Comment: wana to put my C# code that populate my flexi grid ?

Comment: It doesn't generate the fexigrid content, always says : "Processing, please wait .."

Comment: yes,it shows that until its xmlhttprequest completed successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your json format is incorrect, the single quote should be a double quote for strings

Comment: Yes, you're right, now it can show column name, but not the data

Comment: i found we should use json instead of JSON, it solved. thanks!

Comment: By the way, i want know what's difference to use single quote or double quote, and i find it's same JSON objects using firebug

Comment: According to http://www.json.org, "A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be nested" therefore single quotes are not permitted.